# Scheme looping through list

Tags: scheme

I am trying to write some code that will loop through a list and add like terms. I'm trying to `cons` the `cdr` of the input list to a null list and then just compare the `car` of the list to the `car` of the new list and traverse down the list but my code just isn't working. What am I doing wrong here?

```
  (define loop-add
  (lambda (l temp outputList)
    (if (or (equal? (cdr l) '()) (equal? (pair? (car l)) #f))
        outputList
        (if (equal? l '())
            outputList
            (let ((temp (cdr l)))
              (if (equal? temp '())
                  (loop-add (cdr l) outputList)
                  (if (equal? (cdr (car l)) (cdr (car temp)))
                      (loop-add l (cdr temp) (cons (append (cdr (car l)) (cdr (car (cdr l)))) outputList))
                      (loop-add l temp outputList))))))))
```

but the problem now is at the end line its just going to be an infinite loop. I need a way to recur with the input list but with temp being the cdr of the previous temp list.

Comment: Side note: Instead of, e.g., `(car (car (cdr l)))`, you can write `(caadr l)`.

Comment: your algorithm wont solve the problem - if you traverse the list only once, you cant compare every pair to every other pair, the best you can do with one loop thru the list is compare adjacent pairs, or compare all pairs to another pair, the first pair for example. although that isnt enough - as you yourself show in the example where the two like pairs are not adjacent and neither is the first in the list... try think of a way to be able to compare every pair to every other pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by writing a procedure that can transform your input list into a new list of the unique terms in the original list, so

```
(get-unique-terms '((2 1) (3 4) (5 3) (2 4)))
(1 4 3) ; or something like that
```

Call this new list TERMS. Now for each element in TERMS you can search the original list for matching elements, and get a sum of the coefficients:

```
(define (collect-like-terms l)
  (let ((terms (get-unique-terms l)))
    ;; For each element of TERMS,
    ;;   Find all elements of L which have a matching term,
    ;;      Sum the coefficients of those elements,
    ;;      Make a record of the sum and the term a la L.
    ;; Collect the results into a list and return.
```

Comment: Well, could you loop over a list and compare each element to a hard-coded value?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution in Racket:

```
(define (loop-add l)
  (define table
    (for/fold ([h (hash)]) ([i l])
       (dict-update h (cadr i) (lambda (v) (+ v (car i))) 0)))
  (dict-map table (lambda (key val) (list val key))))

(loop-add '((2 1) (3 4) (5 3) (2 4)))
```